# Passing multiple type of data via AJAX to MVC C# Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using AJAX to get the info from the Razor View and send it to controller

Everything is working but now I need to pass an Array + String so the data could be:

```
// View - Javascript
var idkey = $('#idkey').val();
var selected = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Adm/MyAction',
            traditional: true,
            data: { idkey: idkey, selected: selected }), ...

// Controller
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> MyAction(string idkey, string[] selected)
{
  // Do something with the data passed on params
}
```

The issue is ... I can't find anywhere how to send two different types of data from AJAX to controller

Comment: The Task controller receives directly the request body as param ?

Comment: @CesarePolonara well ... if I did not get you wrong ... yes. I'm using the same structure and logic for another parts of my project ... but passing only strings on AJAX data

Comment: I mean, your ajax sends a request body with a type interface of an object / dictionary:

interface : { idkey: string, selected: string[] } . 
Your C# Controller method takes 2 different params, string and string[], so I'm asking if there is an intermediate body parser before the controller.

Comment: @CesarePolonara No ... I have not any parser ... I thought when you send on AJAX data ... it goes with the same type ... as you can see it's a string on AJAX and I'm asking for a string on Controller method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Index900(string theValue, string[] stringArray)
    {
        //put breakpoint here
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("this is the Value" + theValue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#theBtn").click(function () {

                var idkey = $('#idkey').val();
                var selected = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

                var theValue = $("#theInput").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Index900",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ theValue: idkey, stringArray: selected }),
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error...")
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="theBtn" value="Click to start ajax" />
        <input type="text" id="idkey" value="Some Value" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Daniel Lima Fortes let me know if you want me to create a fiddle.